# React Native formik

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to pass the value from `formik` to my `handleSubmit`?

```
const handleSubmit = async(valuesToSubmit) =>    {
      alert("Email", valuesToSubmit.UserData['Email'])
}
<Formik
   initialValues={UserData}
   onSubmit={(values) =>{  handleSubmit(values)}}>
   {(props) => (
   <View style={formStyles.SectionStyle}>
      <TextInput
            name="Email"
            value={props.values['Email']}
            style={formStyles.inputStyle}
            underlineColorAndroid="#f000"
            placeholderTextColor="#8b9cb5"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            onChangeText={props.handleChange('Email')}
      />
```

this is the error i received

[image]

UPDATE
I change the

```
alert("Email", valuesToSubmit.UserData['Email'])
```

to

```
alert(valuesToSubmit['Email'])
```

and this is the result

[image]

the value fetch from my api

[image]

Comment: It should be  valuesToSubmit['Email'] not  valuesToSubmit.UserData['Email']

Comment: hi again, the result is `undefined`

Comment: Does the textinput show a value ?

Comment: Ive posted the updated question

Comment: are you calling props.handleSubmit somewhere ?

Comment: ` onSubmit={(values) =>{  props.handleSubmit(values)}}` you mean this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231510/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-user14823468).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using the same handleSubmit in the button as well, So change the submit button code like below

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={formStyles.buttonStyle}
  activeOpacity={0.5}
  disabled={!props.isValid}
  onPress={props.handleSubmit}
>
```

Avoid using same names for functions.